# Spaces being turned into &nbsp; in angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using ng_repeat to display text from an object.  On the rails backend I call `strip_tags(text)` to remove html. When looking at the output it looks fine.  Even when looking at the object in 'view source' it looks fine.

It only looks weird when you look at the text that is actually rendered from the ng_repeat - after a certain point (200 words in the example below) every space is replaced by an `&nbsp;`

This is causing the text to overflow the div.  Any suggestions for dealing with this?

[image: Screenshot of console]

Edit:  Some of the code (simplified)

JS:

```
$scope.init = function(id){
  $scope.episodes = gon.episodes
```

Haml:

```
.episode-edit{ng_repeat:"episode in episodes"}
  %p {{episode.sanitized_summary}}
```

Comment: Can you share the ``ng-repeat`` code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, turns out it had nothing to do with angular, more to do with Ruby.

Ruby's whitespace regex doesn't capture unicode non-breaking space.

Instead of `str.gsub(/\s/m, ' ')` you have to use `str.gsub(/[[:space:]]/m, ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

You should try `ng-bind-html`. Your snippet would look like

```
<p ng-bind-html="YourObject"></p>
```

You can use it in `ng-repeat` as well.

If you want to secure the data first then include `$sce` service in your controller. Your snippet would be like

```
var ExampleCtrl = function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.YourObject = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.YourObject); // that's it
}
```

Comment: Answer is probably working, though it would be useful to point out the security issues with this solution.

Comment: check my edited answer and don't forget to accept the answer for future uses